# Compare elements in list in F#

Tags: list, f#

I am trying to find the minimum element in a list in F#. Here's my code:

```
    let rec list_minl lst = 
    match lst with 
    | [] -> failwith "Empty list" 
    | hd -> hd 
    | hd::tl when hd < tl -> list_minl tl
```

But when I run the program this error comes out:

> ```
> FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>     'a    
> but given a
>     'a list    
> The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''a list'
> ```

Why?

Comment: This function already exists in the F# core library: [List.min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353412).

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems here - but I will just address the immediate one.

```
hd::tl when hd < tl
```

compares `hd` which is an element, with `tl` which is a list.  You want to compare `hd` with the minimum of `tl`

Answer (score 1):

As @John Palmer stated in his answer, your current code compares an element of type T with a list of type T, which can not work.

I assume you want to find the smallest number from a list of numbers. One possible solution would be to use an accumulator for the minimal value (because you need to *preserve* the currently found minimal value on every iteration):

```
let rec list_minl lst min = 
    match lst with 
    | h1::tl when h1 > min -> list_minl tl min
    | h1::tl when h1 < min -> list_minl tl h1
    | h1::tl (* when h1 = min *) -> list_minl tl min
    | [] -> min
```

The initial value of the accumulator could be for example the first element from the list:

```
let lst = [10;5;2;5;100;6;3]
list_minl lst (List.head lst) |> Console.WriteLine
```

The output is:

```
2
```

You could hide the recursive function and the initial min. value, so that the list_min takes only one parameter (the list):

```
let rec list_minl lst =
    let rec ilist_minl lst min = 
        match lst with
        (* if first element is bigger than current min, preserve min *)
        | h1::tl when h1 > min -> ilist_minl tl min
        (* if first element is smaller than current min, new min is current first element *)
        | h1::tl when h1 < min -> ilist_minl tl h1
        (* first element equals min, preserve min *)
        | h1::tl (* when h1 = min *) -> ilist_minl tl min
        (* processing is done *)
        | [] -> min 

    ilist_minl lst (List.head lst)

list_minl [10;5;2;5;100;6;3] |> Console.WriteLine
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: Using Int32.MaxValue as a fixed supplied value makes the function very specific though.  The only thing a min function strictly needs is a concept of greater than and less than, hence why the built in `List.min` has signature `List.min : 'T list -> 'T (requires comparison)`.  You can just as easily use the first value in the list as the basis for comparison.

Comment: @TheInnerLight you are correct - thanks for the hint. I have changed the example code.